# Binary search with gaps

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

Let's imagine two arrays like this:
[8,2,3,4,9,5,7]

[0,1,1,0,0,1,1]

How can I perform a binary search only in numbers with an 1 below it, ignoring the rest?
I know this can be in O(log n) comparisons, but my current method is slower because it has to go through all the 0s until it hits an 1.

Comment: I don't mean that. I want to do a binary search on the first array, but ONLY to numbers that have a 1 in the same index of the second array, Ignoring the rest, so it doesnt matter if the rest if sorted or not.

Comment: Binary search itself is O(log n), but it requires the input array to be sorted. Sorting can be done in O(n * log n), and filtering the values associated with 1s in the second array can be done in O(n). Therefore, the overall algorithm will be O(n * log n). You can't do better than that with binary search.

Comment: I'll explain it differently: here is the same example as before:[8,2,3,4,9,5,7]

[0,1,1,0,0,1,1] If we ignore the numbers in the first array with a 0 below, the first array would look like this [2,3,5,7] it is sorted, so we can do binary search. The target is to ignore the rest of the numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hit a number with a 0 below, you need to scan in both directions for a number with a 1 below until you find it -- or the local search space is exhausted. As the scan for a 1 is linear, the ratio of 0s to 1s determines whether the resulting algorithm can still be faster than linear.

Comment: O(n) worst time complexity doesn't make sense for a binary search. There arent any more efficient ways?

Comment: Well I think it's still O(log n) if you have only log(n) zeros. If you have more zeros, the search for ones will dominate and you'll get closer to linear time. The problem is that the values with 0s are not sorted, so you can't use binary search to skip them. Hence, if there are too many, skipping them will dominate the total time.

Comment: That is a big problem. I am trying to make a O(nlogn) sorting algorithm  that only does n swaps. I need to do that binary search n times, so if each search is O(n) in worst case (everything are 0s) its performance would approximate to O(n squared). I'm doing a bit more of research, maybe I need another kind of data structure.

Comment: Well maybe you should state the full original problem in the question then?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old, but I've just discovered a wonderful little trick to solve this problem in most cases where it comes up.  I'm writing this answer so that I can refer to it elsewhere:

## Fast Append, Delete, and Binary Search in a Sorted Array

---

The need to dynamically insert or delete items from a sorted collection, while preserving the ability to search, typically forces us to switch from a simple array representation using binary search to some kind of search tree -- a far more complicated data structure.

If you only need to insert at the end, however (i.e., you always insert a largest or smallest item), or you don't need to insert at all, then it's possible to use a much simpler data structure.  It consists of:

1. A dynamic (resizable) array of items, the **item array**; and
2. A dynamic array of integers, the **set array**.  The set array is used as a [disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), using the single-array representation described here: [How to properly implement disjoint set data structure for finding spanning forests in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004277/how-to-properly-implement-disjoint-set-data-structure-for-finding-spanning-fores/60008858#60008858)

The two arrays are always the same size.  As long as there have been no deletions, the item array just contains the items in sorted order, and the set array is full of singleton sets corresponding to those items.

If items have been deleted, though, items in the item array are only valid if the there is a root set at the corresponding position in the set array.  All sets that have been merged into a single root will be contiguous in the set array.

This data structure supports the required operations as follows:

### Append (O(1))

To append a new largest item, just append the item to the item array, and append a new singleton set to the set array.

### Delete (amortized effectively O(log N))

To delete a valid item, first call search to find the adjacent larger valid item.  If there is no larger valid item, then just truncate both arrays to remove the item and all adjacent deleted items.  Since merged sets are contiguous in the set array, this will leave both arrays in a consistent state.

Otherwise, merge the sets for the deleted item and adjacent item in the set array.  If the deleted item's set is chosen as the new root, then move the adjacent item into the deleted item's position in the item array.  Whichever position isn't chosen will be unused from now on, and can be nulled-out to release a reference if necessary.

If less than half of the item array is valid after a delete, then deleted items should be removed from the item array and the set array should be reset to an all-singleton state.

### Search (amortized effectively O(log N))

Binary search proceeds normally, except that we need to find the representative item for every test position:

```
int find(item_array, set_array, itemToFind) {
    int pos = 0;
    int limit = item_array.length;
    while (pos < limit) {
        int testPos = pos + floor((limit-pos)/2);
        if (item_array[find_set(set_array, testPos)] < itemToFind) {
            pos = testPos + 1; //testPos is too low
        } else {
            limit = testPos; //testPos is not too low
        }
    }
    if (pos >= item_array.length) {
        return -1;  //not found
    }
    pos = find_set(set_array, pos);
    return (item_array[pos] == itemToFind) ? pos : -1;
}
```

Comment: Anyone please comment if you've seen this is the literature.