# is there disjoint sets data structure in any of javas 3rd party "known" libraries like gueva/apache collections

Tags: java, data-structures, disjoint-sets

I've been looking around searching for any *"known"* Java data structure library(Like google's **guava** for example) that have disjoint sets data structure...

Java's Collections doesn't have it apparently.

Implementing it myself is not an option...

So is there any **known** public Java library that has this data structure?

Comment: Are [Collections.disjoint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,java.util.Collection%29) and [Set.removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) not sufficient?

Comment: Why is implementing it yourself not an option?  It's super easy. I usually do the whole job in a single `int[]`.  See, for example, my python implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004277/how-to-properly-implement-disjoint-set-data-structure-for-finding-spanning-fores/60008858#60008858

Comment: @VGR no... how is that even related? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure