# How to overcome CPU limit exceeded verdict

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to solve [Nearest Light](https://toph.co/p/nearest-light) problem on [Toph](https://toph.co/). The nearest turned-on bulb's position can either be the same bulb, or some other bulbs to its left or right or 5000001st bulb in case all the bulbs between 0 and 5000000 are turned off. Also turning a bulb off affects other bulbs.

Suppose our bulbs position is 1100100 (0 means off and 1 means the bulb is on) then our Right and Left array( Right array says the step from each bulb needed to have the nearest turned on bulb at Right and same for left array ) will look something like this R = [0,0,2,1,0,2,1] and L = [0,0,1,2,0,1,2] if we turn off 4th(0 indexed) bulb then bulbs position is 1100000 and then R = [0,0,5,4,3,2,1] and L = [0,0,1,2,3,4,5]. for *ith* bulb if n+Right[i] > 5000000 then we print Left[i] or if n-Left[i] < 0 then we print Right[i].

Here is what I've tried.

```
#define min(a,b) ((a>b) ? b : a)

int Right   [5000001] ; 
int Left    [5000001] ;

#define SIZE 5000000

int main()
{
    int Q;
    scanf("%i",&Q);
    memset(Left,0,sizeof(int)*SIZE + 1 );
    memset(Right,0,sizeof(int)*SIZE + 1 );
    int one_two, n;
    while (Q--)
    {
        scanf("%i %i",&one_two,&n);
        if(one_two == 1)
        {
            Right[n] = -1; Left[n] = -1;
            if(n == 0){
                Left[n] = 1;
                Right[n] = Right[n+1] + 1;
                continue;
            }
            if(n == SIZE){
                Right[n] = 1;
                Left[n] = Left[n-1] + 1;
                continue;
            }
            for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--){
                if(Right[i] == 0)
                    break;
                Right[i] = Right[i+1] + 1;
            }
            for (int i = n; i <= SIZE ; i++){
                if(Left[i] == 0)
                    break;
                Left[i] = Left[i-1] + 1; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (n-Left[n] < 0 && n+Right[n] > SIZE)
            {
                printf("%i\n",Right[n]+1);
                continue;
            }
            if(n-Left[n] < 0){
                printf("%i\n",Right[n]);
                continue;
            }
            if(n+Right[n] > SIZE){
                printf("%i\n",Left[n]);
                continue;
            }
            printf("%i\n", min(Right[n],Left[n]) );
        }
    }
}
```

But is there any simple approach to solve this problem? I am having CLE as verdict.

Comment: "Also turning a bulb off affects other bulbs." I don't see that in the problem statement.

Comment: wow. The problem description is just something .. "*virtual vertical line with infinite length are numbered starting from zero from left to right*" - there is no left and right in a *vertical* line...

Comment: @SayemRahman Your program has no description of the algorithm it's using to do work, so I have no idea what R and L are and why there would be anything but 0s and 1s in them.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It says it is a virtual vertical line. The virtual vertical line is implemented as a physical horizontal line. They are isomorphic, so this is a valid virtualization.

Comment: Please don't add the algorithm description in comments. Please _edit_ your question and add it there. People aren't going to want to scroll down a bunch of comments to get what should have been in the question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pretty much constant time per query using a [disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

When a light is turned off, you make a new set for it and merge it with its (0 to 2) neighbors that are also off.

Since only adjacent lights are merged, every root set corresponds to a contiguous range of lights.  In every root set, you should additionally track the range of lights that it covers.

When you need to find the nearest on light to a light that is off, you find its root set, inspect its range, and choose whichever side is closest.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004277/how-to-properly-implement-disjoint-set-data-structure-for-finding-spanning-fores/60008858#60008858) for an applicable disjoint set implementation.

If you implement it reasonably well, this algorithm should be must faster than the 0.6 seconds taken by the fastest answer currently recorded on Toph.