# Consequences of disjoint set union path compression in union by size

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, disjoint-sets

When doing union by size, you compare the size of the nodes that you're trying to unify.
I found this code on codeforces that shows how to build a DSU with path compression and union by size:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class DSU
{
public:
    unordered_map<int, int> parent;
    unordered_map<int, int> size;

    void make_set(int v)
    {
        parent[v] = v;
        size[v] = 1;
    }

    int find_set(int v)
    {
        if (v == parent[v])
            return v;

        return parent[v] = find_set(parent[v]);
    }

    void union_sets(int a, int b)
    {
        a = find_set(a);
        b = find_set(b);

        if (a != b)
        {
            if (size[a] < size[b])
                swap(a, b);

            // a big, b small
            // attach small tree to big tree
            parent[b] = a;
            size[a] += size[b];
        }
    }
};
```

**The question is**, don't you have to modify `find_set` to decrease the size of the parent node since the parent node will be pointing to the root now and not to another child node ?

Wouldn't this be the correct implementation of `find_set`?

```cpp
    int find_set(int v)
    {
        if (v == parent[v])
            return v;

        size[parent[v]] -= 1;
        return parent[v] = find_set(parent[v]);
    }
```

Comment: Side notes: (1) [#include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) (2) [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: I don't know the algorithm (though I found this [link](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/disjoint_set_union.html). I would not expect a find method to modify anything at all. I would expect it to be declared as `int find_set(int v) const`

Comment: We only ever care about the size of the roots, not of intermediate nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you gain nothing since that parent is not the representative of the set.

That is,

```
int find_set(int v)
{
    if (v == parent[v])
        return v;
    
    // This parent is not the representative, changing
    // the size is superfluous as it will no longer 
    // be referenced again.
    size[parent[v]] -= 1;
    return parent[v] = find_set(parent[v]);
}
```

Comment: And, since you never need both a size and a link, you only need one array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004277/how-to-properly-implement-disjoint-set-data-structure-for-finding-spanning-fores/60008858#60008858