# How to sort intervals into minimum number of bins without overlapping intervals

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization

I'm looking for an algorithm to achieve the following:

Given an arbitrary set of "intervals", where an interval is defined simply by a start and an end (2 floating point numbers with `end >= start`). I would like to organise these intervals into 1 or more "bins"/"buckets"/groups such that:

1. No two intervals within a single bin overlap each other
2. The minimum number of bins is used

My solution has been to iterate the intervals and for each one, essentially perform a binary search on each bin until one is found which can accommodate the interval (new bin if necessary). This works but I'm left wondering if it can be optimised because depending on the order in which the intervals are processed, the result is different. I have a feeling that sorting the intervals from largest to smallest (`end - start`) gives better results but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the intervals by their end point, and then take each interval in end-point order, and put it into the bucket with the largest right-most end point, such that bucket.max_endpoint < interval.startpoint.  If there is no such bucket, then you have to start a new one.

If you keep the buckets in a binary search tree sorted by max_endpoint, then you can find the best one in log(|buckets|) time, for O(N log N) all together.

The proof that choosing the tightest fit interval for each bucket is optimal is simple:

Imagine that you already know an optimal assignment of intervals to buckets, and you put them into the buckets in endpoint order, and at some point you *don't* choose the tightest-fit bucket...

If you change your mind and choose the tightest-fit bucket instead, you'll be in the same situation, except that one of the buckets will have *more* room on the right.  It never hurts to have more room, so the remaining intervals will still fit.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting take... I think I see where you're coming from but I don't completely follow you. 1. When you say to sort by end point, do you mean increasing or decreasing order? 2. Currently I use a binary search to find where to place each interval within a given bucket (maybe it fits somewhere in the middle for example), this search returns the index at which to insert the new interval into that bucket. But you are talking about using a binary search to find the right bucket (based on max_endpoint)? Some pseudo-code would be really helpful!

Comment: Yes, by endpoint in increasing order. That way you don't have to search the bucket -- it fits at the end or it doesn't fit, and the only thing you have to know about a bucket is its highest endpoint, because all further intervals are higher than that.  Also, you can prove that choosing the tightest-fit bucket is an optimal choice.

Comment: Ah yes I understand you now! My method of binary searching each bucket seem horribly inefficient by comparison. I think I'll do some performance tests and compare :D Do you have any source / reading material on that last point, a proof that this approach is optimal? I'd be very interested to learn a bit more detail behind the topic. Thanks again.

Comment: I made this algorithm up just for this question, so I have no references to provide.  I did add the proof of optimality to the answer, though.

Comment: Thanks again Matt, you've been a great help.

Comment: While thinking about this question, I've just discovered a wonderful little trick that you can use to avoid making a search tree: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70217806/5483526